# ProductBundle exception: Product has no field or association named

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sylius

The thing is that `$this->_getContainer()->get('sylius.repository.product')->findOneBy(array('my_attribute' => '1234'))` throws exception: 
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 209 near 'my_attribute = :my_attribute': Error: Class Sylius\Component\Product\Model\Product has no field or association named my_attribute

What is the reason for that? 
I am using just clean Sylius SyliusProductBundle, SyliusAttributeBundle and some other required. 
Saving the products with different attributes works like a charm, but trying to load product by any of non-standard attributes results with this exception. 
I didn't extend any model, I didn't configure any XML or YML by adding any of new attributes. From EAV I would expect to create a required attribute on-the-fly (which work) and do not have to define any fixed attributes. 
E.g. I would like to have wines (with attributes grape, year) and also cars (with engine, length and type).

But maybe I am wrong? How to fix it? Can you provide some examples? The one from documentation doesn't work as you see.

`$this->_getContainer()->get('sylius.repository.product')->findAll()` returns all products from my database, but without saved attributes nor values. But in tables sylius_product, sylius_product_attribute, sylius_product_attribute_value everything looks to be OK.

Any hints are appreciated. Even stupid - I am completely new to Symfony 2.

Comment: Could you post your complete action, what version of Symfony 2 are you using ?

Comment: @SylvainMARTIN  I can't post action, because it is not a controller. 
I am implementing `class Importer extends ContainerAware`, so the only change to the code posted before could be:

`$this->container->get('sylius.repository.product')->findOneBy(array('sku' => '1234'));`
There is nothing more relevant to issue of loading products with related attributes.

`"name": "symfony/symfony",
            "version": "v2.7.2",
         `

Comment: `"symfony/symfony": "v2.7.2"`, `"sylius/product":"v0.14.0"`

Comment: I've updated my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a custom method in your product repository:

```
public function findByAttribute($attributeName, $value) 
{
    return $this->getQueryBuilder()
        ->join($this->getAlias() . '.attributes', 'av')
        ->join('av.attribute', 'a')
        ->where('av.value = :value')
        ->andWhere('a.name = :attributeName')
        ->setParameter('attributeName', $attributeName)
        ->setParameter('value', $value)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: @gvf The problem is with all custom attributes. SKU was just an example of such an custom attribute. I created it using addAttrbiute() method and see it in sylius_product_attribute. It was just coincidence that I choose SKU to explain the problem and definitely luck of experience in this bundle (I was not aware of SKU concept on variants level). 
Anyway I edited my question to show it's not all about SKU only.

Comment: @gvf Thank you for editing your answer and your involvement. 
Unfortunately it does not explain what is the problem with findOneBy() native method. 
My implementation already includes direct queries, but it is not the clean solution that I am looking for.

Comment: @PatrykM. The problem is that you are trying to do a search on `Product` by a field `my_attribute`, and your product doesn't have that field. Product has an `attributes` property that holds an `ArrayCollection` of attributes which are of type `Sylius\Component\Product\Model\Attribute`. So you cannot do a direct search, you have to do the joins with the different objects.

Comment: Thanks @gvf
So Sylius documentation is really confusing: [link]http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusProductBundle/product.html
'$products = $repository->findBy(array('special' => true)); // Find products matching some custom criteria.'